# I want to push to github using my ssh key, however it still prompts me for a username and password

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I've added my key to github, so maybe my machine just refuses to use ssh keys? If so, please tell me how to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. Find the ssh URL details, it could be achieved by pressing on 'clone or download' and switching to ssh.

Then just enter your terminal, inside the repository folder: `git remote set-url origin NEWURL`. Replace NEWURL with your valid ssh URL.